# Eclipse only loads log4.properties from Test Folder

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat, maven, log4j

I am using Eclipse Helios, maven 2.0.4 & the maven plugin for eclipse.

Well, I imported a  Maven WebProject to eclipse with this sentence:
mvn org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-eclipse-plugin:2.6:eclipse -Dwtpversion=2.0

The project has a log4j.properties file in "src/test/resources" and another one
"src/main/resources".

When I run the WebProject into Tomcat 6.0 trough Eclipse (Clicking in Run As..), the project loads the log4j.properties from "src/test/resources" rather than "src/main/resources". I dont know why. Also I put a log4j.properties in Tomcat Folder (\lib) and the project still loads the file from "src/test/resources".

Could you please shed some light in this issue?.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I think that it is possible if in Assembly section of your project settings there is a line with test resources after all other folders.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Hi Alexey, thanks for your reply. Yes, I've checked again the Assembly section and I was deploying test/resources to Tomcat for mistake. Now everything is working fine.